# How to determine where a piece of code should go in ReduxJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am following the tutorial over at https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

However, I am stuck with the following, as the author doesn't tell you where to put the following code.

I am up to "Implementing Container Components":

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
    default:
      return todos
  }
}
​
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}
```

That is the code that needs to go in one of the created files, or maybe a new file. However the article does not state where or how to do this. I am a beginner with nodejs, reactjs & reduxjs.

Comment: How did you get on with the assistance provided below, Russell?

Comment: Did my answer provide enough assistance to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code definitely goes into your component. More  precisely, if you separate your components into [presentational components and containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635800/redux-presentational-components-vs-container-component) this should go into your container.

> To use connect(), you need to define a special function called mapStateToProps that describes how to transform the current Redux store state into the props **you want to pass to a presentational component you are wrapping.**

As you can see in the example, the snippet has a `mapStateToProps` function.

The `getVisibleTodos` is merely a "selector" to transfer the state into something your component can use. Have a look at the [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library for more advanced means of selecting/caching/assembling redux-store values.

[Here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples) you find a few github projects corresponding to the examples described on redux.js.org. For example the [todos example](https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples#todos) repo. Have a look how the project is structured and [where the code goes exactly](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos/src/containers/VisibleTodoList.js).

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to go in the reducer file.

You might want to check out the full documentation [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/introduction/basic-tutorial.md) about the usage of redux reducer.

It contains different tutorials, but might help you solve the one in the docs page.

Comment: The switch case in the code above indeed resembles a reducer, but it is not :)