# Reactjs - Best pattern for multiple views for same logical component

Tags: reactjs

I have a logical component "" which I need to generate few views for ("ActivitySliding" or "ActivityLarge", etc). All the views should behave the same (say open dialog on click, calculate price, etc). What is the best pattern for that scenario?

Comment: Your questions need more description, what exactly you want to do, What have you done so far? the terms like `logical component ` , `ActivitySliding` ,... are not standard platform terms, to know what exactly you mean

Comment: But in general, first, make a search for conditional rendering, to see if that is what you need

Comment: This question, even if it should provide some codes for one view, is definitely a crucial question and should receive more upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a pattern. We use for example containers and components.

As you said you need a few views with the same behaviour and content.

So create a component for that. And for the data use containers.

You can find more information about containers and components [Redux Presentational Components Vs Container Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635800/redux-presentational-components-vs-container-component)

Comment: Make sense. 2 Presentational Components with no state to present 2 different views, rendered by a Container Component that is managing states and logic for the feature. This answer can be accepted.